# When the site changes to use `www` does the XML sitemap need to be resubmitted via Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap

My website's sitemap was previously submitted to Google Search Console without `www`. Now I asked the domain provider to change my domain URL include `www`. Do I need to resubmit the website URL in my Google Search Console account with `www.`?

Comment: But why do you even care about www?  Why not redirect people to the non www URL?

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to re-authenticate your new www site. www is a subdomain, and unless your registered a domain with all it's subdomains to Google Search Console, you need to register every subdomain. Since you need open a new asset in Google Search Console, you will also need to resubmit your sitemap.xml

Thanks to the comment from Stephen, I am adding a screenshot:

[image]

Stephen is correct, if you have verified a domain property, you are good to go. If you have verified a single url property, you might need to verify the www property.

Comment: Authentication usually works for both www, and no-www.   I've never had to upload different verification files for the two of those.   I think you might mean that they should add a separate property with www.  Unless of course they already have multiple properties or have verified a domain property.

Comment: Thanks for noting, I edited my answer.