# What to do in Google Search Console when moving a subdomain to its own domain

Tags: seo, google-search-console, 301-redirect, subdomain, migration

I found this [post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/133971/when-the-site-changes-to-use-www-does-the-xml-sitemap-need-to-be-resubmitted-v) but I it doesn't answer my question completely.
I have

- `https://de.example.com`
- `https://es.example.com`
- and others

which I moved using `301` to

- `https://example.de`
- `https://example.es`
- ...

The redirects work perfectly.

Currently do exist in the Google Search Console the following sitemaps URL:

- `https://de.example.com/sitemap.xml`
- `https://es.example.com/sitemap.xml`
- ...

In the Search Console I already added/confirmed `example.de`, `example.es`, ... as new properties.

How can I *tell* the Search Console that these subdomains have been permanently moved so the existing ranking doesn't get lost?

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I was further investigating and I found a solution. There is the ["Change of Address Tool"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9370220?hl=en).

In my case there was the situation that I didn't have created yet in the Search Console for the subdomains the `URL prefix` properties.

*First I had to do some preparation:*

1. `301 Permanent Forward` from `https://de.domain.com` --> `https://domain.de` - already working
2. Adding all subdomains as `URL prefix` property. For example `https://de.domain.com`.
3. Adding a `Domain` property. For example `domain.de`.

Then I ran `Settings` | `Change of address` for each subdomain.

Comment: The change of address tool can help speed up the migration. However it's those 301 redirects that are the key thing that tells all search engines that you have moved. You may see a temporary dip in traffic as Google discovers the redirects and later crawls the new URLs.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath Yes, you are right. It's may be only some _psychological_ step as _I_ initiate the change of the address instead of waiting **when** my pages are the next in the scheduler list in the world of Google which is mostly a black hole... :-)